# Just inherited a digital phosphor oscilloscope and trying to figure out why the sine wave is doubled

Tags: oscilloscope, sine

I was just given a Tektronix TDS 3014B and I wanted to learn how to use it.  I setup a simple sine wave generator and I'm working through all the menus.  When I start the sine wave, everything looks fine until I change the vertical scale.  Once I get the vertical scale above a certain threshold, the wave form doubles. It looks like the scope is pulling the inverted phase of the wave as well.

I've looked and I can't find any reason why this would happen.  Is this something from my sine generator, or is there a setting I'm not correctly applying?

[image: Single Sine wave]

[image: Double Sine wave]

Comment: The device has a manual, have you read it? Of course the manual does not directly answer that question, but covers the basics how the device operates so you might understand why it behaves like it does in other situations too.

Comment: The Tektronix TDS 3014B has an LCD, not a CRT. There's no real phosphorus involved.  It has "digital phosphor" which is nothing more than an emulation some of the visual effects of a CRT.

Comment: Tektronix has a lot of good information (including the user/reference manual for your oscilloscope), see tek.com

Comment: Even if it was a CRT they don’t contain phosphorus, the light emitting chemicals are called phosphors, similar name, different chemicals.

Comment: Learn to use Quickmenu on this model of 'scope.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The trigger module is likely having trouble with a slightly noisy waveform. OP's waveform display is slightly out of focus, so it is difficult to see how much high frequency noise is present on that sinusoidal waveform.
 Some possible noise spikes are highlighted. It is easier for me to see noise at waveform peaks, but it is likely that noise spikes occur throughout the sine wave. These noise spikes are particularly egregious if they occur at the critical 50mV trigger voltage. For low-amplitude voltage input, noise may be more apparent, and difficult to trigger properly.
[image: possible noise spikes highlighted from OP's photo #2]
The trigger module has been told "display the waveform on a rising slope, when it passes through 50 mV".
A generally-falling slope of the sine wave can have a momentarily-positive-going slope due to noise when the 50 mV trigger voltage is reached. This causes a mis-trigger that is super-imposed on a properly triggering positive-slope sine wave. (OP's 2nd photo.)

Trigger menus often add some buttons to help stop this kind of mis-triggering...
These might look something like:

- **Noise reject**
- **High-frequency reject**

Comment: Limiting the vertical channel bandwidth can also be helpful.

Comment: High-frequency reject did the trick! Yes, the signal is SUPER noisy.  That's what I'm trying to debug.  I think there is some ground loops or something.

Answer (score 4):

The scope is triggering on both the rising edge and the falling edge of the sine wave zero-crossing point.

You need to adjust the trigger level knob (in the Trigger instrument cluster).

The Trigger Menu should also be set to Mode Normal (instead of Auto). In Auto triggered mode, it will sometimes trigger itself without detecting the trigger level in the signal.

Comment: Thw Auto  mode will always self trigger as it was designed to do. In fact, for beginners it is best to leave it set to Auto so a trace will always be present.

Answer (score 2):

If you are lost you can always, hit the Autoset button. It will set the trigger mode to Auto, DC-coupled Edge triggered, rising slope etc. Your scope has some squirrely trigger mode options such as alternating-channel trigger. Image from [here](https://www.ebay.ca/itm/115728746720):

[image]

It will also take a usually pretty good shot at the channel and horizontal settings.

(The one pictured, from a Singapore eBay listing, has an advanced trigger option module installed so it would have even more trigger options)

However, Autoset changes so many things that you should familiarize yourself with the 'undo' function on your scope (see the user manual).